# How to detect real invoker's name in procedure defined with SQL SECURITY DEFINER characteristic in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, security, stored-procedures

In simplification, I have a MySQL procedure `get_data()`, which selects filtered data for users. Customized filter conditions are stored in database table. Procedure `get_data()` should gets conditions for current user and select only his data by adding a `WHERE` clause.

But when I defined procedure with `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` characteristic, detection current user (invoker) in procedure body is not possible because function `current_user()` returns definer's name, and when I defined procedure with `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` characteristic, the procedure failed because invoker haven't `SELECT` privileges on source table.

Is it possible to create a procedure in MySQL, which selects customized data for user from table not accessible for user?

Currently, I have defined views (one for each user), but the maintenance of this in a situation where conditions in queries are constantly changing is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using user() instead of current_user()?

Comment: Yes. In my case, user() returns 'user1@localhost' and current_user() returns 'user1@%'. Probably the solution is not so simple.

Comment: And what is the login that you have used for the user calling the procedure? How do you log in? And what is the login that you have used to create the procedure?